# Check if user reached the bottom of the page react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am trying to check if an user scrolled the bottom of the page.

I am using this function  to check:

```
const handleScroll = (event) => { 
    const bottom = event.target.scrollHeight - event.target.scrollTop === event.target.clientHeight;

    if(bottom){
        console.log('hello');
    }
}
```

But the thing is my app looks like this :

[image]

Right now the function only works when the inner scrollbar is at the bottom. However i want it to fire when the outer scrollbar reached the bottom.

The entire code looks like this :

```
 const handleScroll = (event) => { 
        const bottom = event.target.scrollHeight - event.target.scrollTop === event.target.clientHeight;

        if(bottom){
            console.log('hello');
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='main' onScroll = {handleScroll}>
            <div className='project-counter'>{filteredProjects.length > 0 ? (<p>Gevonden projecten : {filteredProjects.length}</p>) : null}</div> 
            {pro.map(project => (
                <div className='view-container' key={project._id}>
              
                    <div className='hours-container'>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th className='tb-first'>Datum</th>
                                <th className='tb-first'>medewerker</th>
                                <th>Dienst</th>
                                
                                <th>Toelichting</th>
                                <th>Aantal</th>
                            </tr>

                            {project.projectHours.map(hour => (
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{hour.created_at}</td>
                                    <td>{hour.employee.name}</td>
                                    <td>{hour.type.label}</td>
                                    <td>{hour.note}</td>
                                    <td>{hour.hours.toFixed(2)}</td>
                                </tr>
                            ))}

                        </table>
        
                    </div>

                </div>
            ))}

               
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: add the listener to the window object

Comment: @marzelin i am not entirely sure how I can do this

Comment: check out Intersection observer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the listener to the window object:

```js
const App = () => {
  const handleScroll = () => {

    const bottom = Math.ceil(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight

    if (bottom) {
      console.log('at the bottom');
    }
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, {
      passive: true
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div className = "" >  < /div>

};

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
. {
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like your inner scrollbar belongs to your `div`. Do you have a Component one level higher? Try to find the outer scrollbar in the *browser's developing mode (F12)* and see to which Element it belongs. If it's another div element, then just add the listener with the function `handleScroll` to that Element.